# yum install httpd returns No package httpd available on redhat 6.5

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, yum

First, I illustrate the basic issue:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
#  yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install httpd
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Proxy connection failed: 407
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
#  yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Proxy connection failed: 407
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I believe there is nothing wrong with my proxy configuration. Not sure about the 407 error. yum is able to successfully run `list packages` and perform downloads.

I've already tried a lot of things including the suggestion from this site to use remi repo:
https://gist.github.com/mikestecker/9279520

I know there are other similar questions to this asked already but I believe my situation to be different.

I don't have access to an install ISO, so from what I can see, the best way to move forward is to add an appropriate repo to do the install.

Comment: I am unsure if it is material. I've been able to do other successful installs on the same system. Just earlier: I was able to install php already--all the while yum kept saying 407 error. But I haven't figured out completely what this error 407 is about. Still: I highly suspect that its ok to ignore.

Comment: You're getting a proxy error so forget about everything else and fix the proxy issue at hand.  The real questions that need answering are: 1) do you really need a proxy?  2) do you know the proxy address and port number?

Comment: 407 is "proxy authentication required". Note that IIRC, yum does not look at the usual environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` et al., but has proxy settings in `yum.conf`

Comment: If nothing else changed, then we could assume that the proxy server restrictions were changed.  Perhaps your user account got locked.  You should therefore refer to you IT department.

Comment: I have checked the user account. It is not locked. And I wonder why yum reports that error when it is clearly able to download other things successfully. Like I said previously i was able to install php with the 407 error. I do require a proxy so the earlier installs i had with yum was via the same proxy. I have a separate post about 407 error: https://serverfault.com/questions/848577/yum-proxy-connection-failed-407-on-redhat-6-5

Comment: What is the output of `yum repolist all | grep rhscl` ?

Comment: @GAD3R That returns nothing except for the 407 error

Comment: Isn't it possible that the restriction is limited to specific repos since you say other `yum` operations were successful?  I have serious doubts on the details you give though since you showed us in this question that the repository you use for PHP gives this error (Remi).

Comment: I just did a few tests on my side and the only way I was able to get comparable result with the `httpd` example is to use bad proxy authentication.  I was able to however reproduce part of your problem by removing the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d`.